# cannot convert from 'int' to MsPacman.Ghost.Direction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary, monogame, pacman

I have not used any of this in class but its still a requirement on our project and I'm getting a bit squeezed.

**Summarized:** I have to do a pacman game in 2D using the **monogame extension** on Visual Studio, language is **C#** and the problem is occuring when I try to **move the ghosts**, creating the autonomous moviment, I can not wrap my head around a solution so, here's what I got:

```cs
float dist = Vector2.Distance(position.ToVector2(), targetPosition.ToVector2());

if (dist <= 1)
{
    List<Direction> availableDirections = new List<Direction>();

    foreach (var dir in Surroundings)
        if (game1.Board.board[targetPosition.X / (Game1.outputTileSize) + dir.Value.X, targetPosition.Y / (Game1.outputTileSize) + dir.Value.Y] == ' ')
            availableDirections.Add(dir.Key);

    if (availableDirections.Count == 0) return;

    availableDirections = availableDirections.OrderBy(dir =>
    {
        float distP1 = Vector2.Distance(targetPosition.ToVector2() + Surroundings[dir].ToVector2() * Game1.outputTileSize, game1.Player.position.ToVector2());
        return distP1;
    }).ToList();

    direction = availableDirections[0];

    direction = Surroundings[availableDirections.Count - 1];


    targetPosition = targetPosition + availableDirections[direction].Game1.outputTileSize;
}
else
{
    //Position is not the same, move the guy
    Vector2 vec = targetPosition.ToVector2() - position.ToVector2();
    vec.Normalize();
    position = (position.ToVector2() + vec).ToPoint();
    //Incrementar frame
    if ((position.X + position.Y) % 4 == 0)
        frame++;
    if (frame > 1) frame = -1;

}
```

I've tried to instantiate a different kind of list still using the dictionary,but the issue is that it's not recognizing the position on the list as an integer and it clashes. Here's the rest of the code that's relevant to understand the way everything connects:

```cs
namespace MsPacMan
{
    public class Ghost : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        //enumeradores
        enum Orientation { Horizontal, Vertical }

        enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }

        #region variables

        private Texture2D texture;

        private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        private SoundEffect eatghostSound;

        private Game1 game1;

        private int ghostType;

        private Board board;

        private Orientation orientation;

        public Point position, targetPosition, origin;

        int enemyLives = 4;

        int patrolSize;

        int patrolPosition = 0;

        int direction = 1;

        int frame = 0;

        public static int ghostValue = 200;

        Dictionary<Direction, Vector2> ghostColor;

        Dictionary<Direction, Point> Surroundings;

        Direction gDirection = Direction.Up;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Ghost(Game1 game, int x, int y, int ghostType) : base(game)
        {
            orientation = Game1.rnd.Next(2) > 0 ? Orientation.Horizontal : Orientation.Vertical;

            texture = game.SpriteSheet;

            spriteBatch = game.SpriteBatch;

            this.ghostType = ghostType;

            position.Y = y;

            position.X = x;

            targetPosition = position;

            game1 = game;

            board = game1.Board;

            origin = targetPosition = position;

            patrolSize = 2 + Game1.rnd.Next(4);

            eatghostSound = game1.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("pacman_eatghost");

            Surroundings = new Dictionary<Direction, Point>
            {
                [Direction.Up] = new Point(0, -1),
                [Direction.Down] = new Point(0, 1),
                [Direction.Left] = new Point(-1, 0),
                [Direction.Right] = new Point(0, 1),
            };

            ghostColor = new Dictionary<Direction, Vector2>
            {
                [Direction.Right] = new Vector2(0, ghostType),
                [Direction.Left] = new Vector2(2, ghostType),
                [Direction.Up] = new Vector2(4, ghostType),
                [Direction.Down] = new Vector2(6, ghostType),
            };

        }


        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public Board Board => board;

        #endregion

        #region Methods


        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Rectangle pRect = new Rectangle(game1.Player.position, new Point(Game1.outputTileSize));

            Rectangle EnemyArea = new Rectangle(((position.ToVector2()) * Game1.outputTileSize).ToPoint(), new Point(Game1.outputTileSize));

            ChasePattern(ghostType);

            if (EnemyArea.Intersects(pRect))
            {
                Pellet.GetPelletStatus();

                if (Pellet.powerPellet)
                {
                    this.Die();
                }

                else
                {
                    game1.Player.Die();
                }

            }
        }

        //Draws the different types of ghosts
        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Rectangle outRect = new Rectangle(position.X * Game1.outputTileSize, position.Y * Game1.outputTileSize, Game1.outputTileSize, Game1.outputTileSize);

            Rectangle sourceRec = new Rectangle(((ghostColor[gDirection] + Vector2.UnitX * frame) * 16).ToPoint(), new Point(15));

            Rectangle sourcePelletRec = new Rectangle(8 * 16, 0, 16, 15);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            Pellet.GetPelletStatus();

            if (!Pellet.powerPellet)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, outRect, sourceRec, Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, outRect, sourcePelletRec, Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        public void Die()
        {
            eatghostSound.Play();

            enemyLives--;

            int n = 4 - enemyLives;

            AssignGhostValue(n);

            game1.Ghosts.Remove(this);

            game1.Components.Remove(this);

            position = targetPosition = origin;

            game1.Ghosts.Add(this);

            game1.Components.Add(this);
        }

        public void AssignGhostValue(int n)
        {
            ghostValue = ghostValue * n;

            game1.Player.Score += ghostValue;
        }

        public void ChasePattern(int ghostType)
        {
            int ghosType = ghostType;

            int blinky = 0, pinky = 1, inky = 2, clyde = 3;

            if (ghosType == blinky)
            {
                ChaseAggressive();
            }
            else if (ghosType == pinky)
            {
                ChaseAmbush();
            }
            else if (ghosType == inky)
            {
                ChasePatrol();
            }
            else if (ghosType == clyde)
            {
                ChaseRandom();
            }
        }

        public void ChaseAggressive()
        {
            //Blinky the red ghost is very aggressive in its approach while chasing Pac - Man and will follow Pac-Man once located


            float dist = Vector2.Distance(position.ToVector2(), targetPosition.ToVector2());

            if (dist <= 1)
            {
                List<Direction> availableDirections = new List<Direction>();


                foreach (var dir in Surroundings)
                    if (game1.Board.board[targetPosition.X / (Game1.outputTileSize) + dir.Value.X, targetPosition.Y / (Game1.outputTileSize) + dir.Value.Y] == ' ')
                        availableDirections.Add(dir.Key);

                if (availableDirections.Count == 0) return;

                availableDirections = availableDirections.OrderBy(dir =>
                {
                    float distP1 = Vector2.Distance(targetPosition.ToVector2() + Surroundings[dir].ToVector2() * Game1.outputTileSize, game1.Player.position.ToVector2());
                    return distP1;
                }).ToList();

                direction = availableDirections[0];

                direction = Surroundings[availableDirections.Count - 1];


                targetPosition = targetPosition + availableDirections[direction]. Game1.outputTileSize;
            }
            else
            {
                //Position is not the same, move the guy
               Vector2 vec = targetPosition.ToVector2() - position.ToVector2();
                vec.Normalize();
                position = (position.ToVector2() + vec).ToPoint();
                //Incrementar frame
                if ((position.X + position.Y) % 4 == 0)
                    frame++;
                if (frame > 1) frame = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what the issue is here. Is an exception thrown? What do you mean with _clashes_? Or is the behaviour just unexcepted?

Comment: There is too much code here.  It looks like you are trying an `enum` to `int`. You can just cast. `Direction dir= (Direction)number;`